# Decoding Huffman Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, huffman-code

I am implementing a function that takes in a tree and an encoded string.
Example:

```
decode(*Huffmantree, "10010101010")
```

I want this function to return decoded string for the encoded string in the input relative to the Huffman tree input.

The code I have so far:

```
string decode(NodePtr root, string encoded_str)
{
    string temp = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < encoded_str.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (root->is_leaf() == true)
        {
            temp[i] = root->letter;
            //cout << root->letter;
        }
        if (root->left != NULL)
        {
            encoded_str.
        }
        if(root->right != NULL)
        {

        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**I am having trouble implementing what happens when either left or right is not NULL, i.e. when I have to continue to the next node.**

Any ideas?

edit:

```
string decode(NodePtr root, string encoded_str)
{
    string temp = "";
    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i < encoded_str.size() ; i++)
    {

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"error in string"<<endl;
        return temp;
        //cout<<root->letter;
    }
    temp[i] = root->letter;
    if(encoded_str[i] == '0')
    {
        root = root->left;
    }
    else
    {
        root = root->right;
    }
    }
//    for (int i = 0 ; i < temp.size(); i++)
//    {
//        cout<<temp[i];
//    }
//    cout<<endl;
    temp[i]='/0';
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following may help:

```
string decode(NodePtr root, string encoded_str)
{
    string res = "";
    NodePtr node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i != encoded_str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (encoded_str[i] == '0') { // left child
            node = node->left;
        } else { // rigth child
            assert(encoded_str[i] == '1');
            node = node->right;
        }
        if (node->is_leaf() == true)
        {
            res += node->letter;
            node = root;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: One question: The assert function.. Does that mean in this case that it terminates if encoded_stri != 1?

Comment: `assert` is used in Debug (when `NDEBUG` is not defined). If the condition fails, then the program stops. You may use other/better error checking to be sure that `encoded_str` contains only `'0'` and `'1'` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This would be one of the simplest code , basically you need to check whether `encoded_str` is valid or not .

**UPDATE :** Now  , the code should work .

```
string decode(NodePtr root, string encoded_str)
{
    string temp = "";
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < encoded_str.size() ; i++)
    {

        if(root == NULL ){
            cout<<"not possible , error in encoded_str";
            return temp;
        }


        if(encoded_str[i]=='0')
            root=  root->left ;
        else
            root=  root->right ;


        if(node->is_leaf()){
            temp+=root->letter;
            return temp;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I am just checking the code. It is not working as it should. I always get "error in string", i.e. it always stops  in the first if sentance

Comment: have you replaced `not possible , error in encoded_str` with a valid c++ cout statement ?

Comment: @user3265963: also include `temp[i]='\0'` , before `return temp;`

Comment: I have done that, it always cout : "error in string"

Comment: @user3265963: try to run it now , your return type is `string` .

Comment: i is not declared int this scope

Comment: put `int i` outside for loop

Comment: yes , always do temp.push_back(..value..) , as this is not c string

Comment: OR , do `temp+=root->letter`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47762/discussion-between-jarod42-and-anon)

Answer (score 0):

When I run this

```
#include <iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


string decode(NodePtr root, string encoded_str)
{
    string temp = "";
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < encoded_str.size() ; i++)
    {

        if(root == NULL ){
            cout<< "not possible , error in encoded_str" << endl;
            return temp;
        }


        if(encoded_str[i]=='0')
            root=  root->left ;
        else
            root=  root->right ;


        if(node->is_leaf()){
            temp+=root->letter;
            return temp;
        }
    }

}



int main()
{

    decode(*Huffmantree, "10010101010");


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the some undefined errors, 
Also there was a quotation error on line 18 I changed.

```
7   IntelliSense: identifier "NodePtr" is undefined c:\Users\Evan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\huffman\huffman\Source.cpp  10  15  huffman
8   IntelliSense: identifier "node" is undefined    c:\Users\Evan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\huffman\huffman\Source.cpp  29  12  huffman
9   IntelliSense: identifier "Huffmantree" is undefined c:\Users\Evan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\huffman\huffman\Source.cpp  42  10  huffman
```

Error   5   error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\users\evan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\huffman\huffman\source.cpp  11  1   huffman
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'root'    c:\users\evan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\huffman\huffman\source.cpp  10  1   huffman
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\users\evan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\huffman\huffman\source.cpp  11  1   huffman
Error   1   error C2065: 'NodePtr' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\evan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\huffman\huffman\source.cpp  10  1   huffman
Error   6   error C2065: 'Huffmantree' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\evan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\huffman\huffman\source.cpp  42  1   huffman
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\evan\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\huffman\huffman\source.cpp  10  1   huffman

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.