# How to traverse through a huffman tree and access stored characters?

Tags: java, huffman-code

I am trying to make a simple program which will accept a string input, generate nodes for every character, generate a huffman tree from these nodes, create a hashmap mapping the characters to their encoded bits, and print the input using the hashmap in huffman coding.

So far I have been successful. The next think I wanted to do was to decompress the compressed string. My approach was to use the huffman tree in such a way that starting from the root, if there is a branch, I will look at the first compressed bit, if it is zero (0), then it will go to the left branch and if it is one (1), it will go to the right branch. Continuing in this manner, for every branch, the next value of the compressed bit will be considered every time until the last node is reached, and the character stored in the node is stored. My program runs fine, however an empty string value is returned when the function is called.

While searching through the answers, I found out that someone had tried a similar approach and had been successful, however it isn't the case for me.
[Decoding Huffman Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854069/decoding-huffman-tree)

This is my current code. The string array contains the compressed string split into individual characters.

```
private  String generateHashTreeHelper(HuffmanTree t, String path, String[] arr) {
            int i = 0;
            while(i < arr.length){
                if(t.isLeaf()){
                    path = path + t.c;
                }
                else{
                    if(arr[i] == "0"){
                        generateHashTreeHelper(t.leftBranch, path + t.leftBranch.c, arr); 
                    }
                    else if(arr[i] == "1"){
                        generateHashTreeHelper(t.rightBranch, path + t.rightBranch.c, arr); 
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            return path;
        }
```

Comment: You have a typo there arr[i] == "0", it will never be true because you're comparing memory positions. Use arr[i].equals("0").

Comment: @CésarFerreira I'm using netbeans for the project. This was suggested by the IDE and I did try it, however it didn't make any difference. It still returns empty string

Answer (score 0):

I translated the code from the [C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854069/decoding-huffman-tree) **exactly** how it was.
It should look something like this:

```
 public String decode(HuffmanTree root, String encodedString)
 {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        HuffmanTree node = root;
        Char[] characters = encodedString.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; ++i) {
            if (characters[i].equals("0")) { // left child
                node = node.getLeft();
            } else { // rigth child
                node = node.getRight();
            }

            if (node.is_leaf() == true) {
                res.append(node.letter);
                node = root;
            }
        }

        return res.toString();
 }
```

And of course I'm assuming you have the class `HuffmanTree` and all needed methods that have been used in this code.